# Tmux will not run from within Cucumber scenario - produces error 'not a terminal'

Tags: ruby, cucumber, tmux

I'm trying to run a Ruby program that runs tmux to create a new session. I'm testing this with Cucumber. The Ruby program by itself works ok and starts the tmux session but when the code is run from the Cucumber scenario I get an error on the console amongst the Cucumber output - 'not a terminal'.

I understand this is due to tmux believing it is not being run in a terminal due to the return value of isatty() which tmux calls on startup.  Why does this happen when running through Cucumber and is there anyway around it as I would really like to be able to test my program with these scenarios.

Comment: You could start tmux in a [pseudo terminal](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/pty/rdoc/PTY.html).

Comment: @Stefan thanks for the suggestion - I really want tmux to start in the current real terminal though, even for testing. I'm ok with it using the real terminal for the Cucumber tests as I want to see it really invoke tmux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I can get around the problem if I start the tmux sessions 'detached' with the -d option. I would prefer to be left inside the tmux session but this is the next best solution and it means I can continue my development with working tests!

I'm still not sure why I get the 'not a terminal' message when running 'tmux new-session' through Cucumber but not when I use the ruby script on the command line directly...